# Error with place holder on jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, next.js

I have a simple react HTML input component and as it used on different sections/pages, I added some props for styling it and its placeholder. The problem is that sometimes I got an error on the compilation(we are using nextjs). 
This the code:

```
{placeHolderColor && (<style jsx>{`input::placeholder{color:${placeHolderColor}}`}</style>)}
```

Basically, I'm using an [inline If with Logical && Operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) inside the **render** function to check if the prop **placeHolderColor** exists, and if exist add the style tag.

The error I'm getting:

> Warning: Unknown prop `jsx` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

The error only occurs when you reload the page. If you made a change and the hot code reloading run, there is no error. Not sure if the problem is the var inside the literal, the '::placeholder' pseudo-element or what. The code works anyway, and if the **placeHolderColor** var is defined the style is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tested your code I got the same error(also on page load). After that I talked to a styled jsx dev with nickname @g (on github @giuseppeg) on ZEIT's #next slack channel https://zeit.chat/ and he confirmed that the conditional use of `<style jsx>` tag is not supported. Here is his explanation https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx/issues/233.

Also, after removing conditional and just inserting your tag like this:

`<style jsx>{'input::placeholder{color:${placeHolderColor}}'}</style>`

I've got this error:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Expected placeHolderColor to not come from the closest scope.
>   Styled JSX encourages the use of constants instead of props or dynamic values which are better set via inline styles or className toggling. See https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#dynamic-styles.

According to recommendations from https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#dynamic-styles, you basically should not add dynamic values into template literals inside `<style jsx>` tag (though you can put there constants and constant expressions starting from version 1.0.4 (see UPDATE at the bottom of the answer for details)). The reason behind the prohibition of using props/dynamic values, according to @giuseppeg comment in the slack thread https://zeit-community.slack.com/archives/C2U01UYEA/p1496928897076534, is following: "at the moment styled-jsx compiles and produces static code and therefore the hashes that make the final CSS unique won't change when the value of a variable like `color` changes"

So, as you see from documentation, it is recommended to use dynamic values via inline styles or className toggling. Unfortunately, styling pseudo-elements (placeholder etc.) in not possible via inline styles in React, so if you have finite number of possible colours then create a class for each colour case and use it like this:

```
const InputWithColouredPlaceholder = props => (
  <div>
    <input
      placeholder="text"
      className={
        'placeholderColourClass' in props && props.placeholderColourClass
      }
    />
    <style jsx>{`
       .reddy::placeholder {
         color: red;
       }
       .greeny::placeholder {
         color: green;
       }
     `}</style>
  </div>
);
```

and render it like `<InputWithColouredPlaceholder placeholderColourClass="reddy" />`

It gets more complicated in case of large range of possible colours though. In this case I would recommend to ask for suggestions in #next channel on ZEIT's slack https://zeit.chat/.

**UPDATE**
Using constants and constant expressions in template literals should work in styled-jsx 1.0.4 (but nextjs currently depends on 1.0.3, and separate installation of styled-jsx will not help, so wait for update of nextjs to support styled jsx 1.0.4). It means that any constants that are not passed trough props and not created inside component should work (for example you can have a js file with constants for colours and import them into your input component). But it does not fit your case because you need a dynamic way.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I was looking for something more dynamic, having the possibility of setting the placeholder color via props and without having presets, but seems is not possible right now.

Comment: ps I added the reason behind preventing the use of dynamic values in the second part of paragraph after the error message.

Comment: pps @giuseppeg also said that they plan to add the possibility to use dynamic values in the future

Answer (score 0):

I got error `Warning: Unknown prop 'jsx' on <style> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see FB react-unknown-prop.` What does that jsx property in your style tag means? Just remove it?

Comment: Adding the jsx attribute makes the styles to only match your component elements as jsx add dynamically attributes to them for using as CSS selector.